# Need help creating console app that outputs percent response for a rating on a survey 1-5 (whole number)

Tags: c#, console

Working on an assignment where i need to accomplish the following: On a survey a question asks the surveyed person  to rate something from 1-5 (whole number). The end user of your program iinputs the answers for that question on an unknown number of surveys. Write a program that allows this and outputs the percent response for each value (1, 2, 3, 4, and 5).

I did a previous Console app with a loop to collect an average and I am unsure how to collect a percent response on 5 different possible inputs.

Below is my previous code.

```
namespace WhileLoopsMean

public class MeanProgram

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        long test, sum, loop, count;
        double avg;
        Console.Write("How many tests? ");
        count = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        sum = 0;
        loop = 1;
        while (loop <= count)
        {
            Console.Write("enter score " + loop + " : ");
            test = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            sum = sum + test;
            loop = loop + 1;
        }
        avg = sum;
        avg = avg / count;
        Console.WriteLine("\naverage : " + avg);

        Console.WriteLine("\n\nenter a score of -100 to end\n");
        count = 1;
        sum = 0;
        Console.Write("enter score " + count + " : ");
        test = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        sum = sum + test;
        while (test != -100)
        {
            count = count + 1;
            Console.Write("enter score " + count + " : ");
            test = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (test != -100)
            {
                sum = sum + test;
            }
            else { }
        }
        count = count - 1;
        avg = sum;
        avg = avg / count;
        Console.WriteLine("\naverage : " + avg);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: You should figure out how you'd do it on paper first, and then translate that to code. Then, if you have a specific problem, ask a new question. See [ask], [tour], and [mcve].

Comment: My issue is i'm confused on how to do it on paper as well. I don't understand how to create the loop to require a input within a specific range of numbers and then to calculate and then calculate the percentages of them. It seems i would create 5 unique variables and calculate the percentage based on the variable/count?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        string input = "";
        List<List<int>> answers = new List<List<int>>();
        int questionsCount = ReadInt32("The number of questions: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < questionsCount; i++) {
            answers.Add(new List<int>());
        }
        while (input == "" || input == "y") {
            for (int i = 0; i < answers.Count; i++) {
                List<int> a = answers[i];
                a.Add(ReadInt32($"Question [{i}]: "));
            }
            input = Read("Continue (y/n)? ").ToLower();
        }
        WriteLine("End of input!");
        for (int i = 0; i < answers.Count; i++) {
            List<int> a = answers[i];
            Write($"Average for question[{i}]: {a.Average()}\n");
        }
        ReadKey();
    }

    static string Read (string a) {
        Write(a);
        return ReadLine();
    }

    static int ReadInt32 (string a = "") {
        Write(a);
        return ToInt32(ReadLine());
    }
}
```

Try this out. You can customize the questions. And note that to use `Write()` and `WriteLine()`, you should add

```
using static System.Console;
```

at the top, in the references of the project.